# How to cover up or fix a dent on a phone?

Tags: hardware, phone

I recently got a new phone.

I recently dropped said new phone on a hard ceramic flooring.

My heart broke in two at this point as I discovered I had dented the phone as the case is a pile of rubbish and doesn't protect the corners.

Now I have to look at this dent every time I use the phone, which is a fair amount, and it slightly distressing.

**I was wondering if there is a method to:**

> remove said dent

**or**

> 'buff' it out or just cover it up with something like paint (but obviously not paint as that's just silly)

---

Some background:

It's an HTC One M9 or 'Hima' in Gunmetal Grey. A small amount of the paint was removed in the traumatic aforementioned incident which takes away from the stunning aesthetics of this phone. I don't want to get a new bulky case that'll hide the problem as I am very particular about my phone cases.

Comment: You have the Dot View case? I got the M8 with it and I got the same problem. By now already all corners lost some of their paint and last week my screen even broke, because the case snaps off of the corner as soon as it hits the ground. Are you satisfied with the M9?

Comment: @Alex No, I couldn't afford like £40 for a case so I just got a small one. I genuinely love it, haven't had an android in a while so still getting used to it but it is a stunner

Comment: I'm tempted to edit the post to say "takes away from the stunning `a e s t h e t i c s` of this phone"

Answer (score 3):

The quickest fix would be a cool 1/2 phone case which would solve two problems. First it would cover the edges of your phone so no more visible dent. Second it would protect your phone from future damages. I have a Tech21 case and its sleek and gets the job done:

https://www.tech21.com/en_us/smartphones/htc-cases/htc-one-m9-cases

Answer (score -1):

use a sharpie marker that matches your phone color it actually works

Comment: Could you add a more detailed explanation of how to perform this repair?